# Excel Spreadsheet - Distributing Master Sheet rows and deleteing duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, macros

I have a master sheet that I have the row distributing to different sheets with specific labels.

[image]

I want to have each row distribute to the appropriate tab (from the Master) dependent on the information in column B.

I was using code to distribute the columns but had no way of deleting/updating columns from the master if they changed.  I then added in an ID# which would be unique to each task.

I tried changing the code to read from column B but I end up with new sheets numbered from 1-31.  The code worked before I added in the ID# column and had the line: `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), _` read `A3`.

My code:

```
Sub ProcessRows()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), _
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    cell.EntireRow.Copy CopyTo(cell)
Next cell
End Sub

'Return a range object to which a row should be copied
'  Range returned is determined by the value in "rng"
Function CopyTo(rng As Range) As Range

Dim s As Excel.Worksheet, sName As String

sName = Trim(rng.Value) 'just in case...

On Error Resume Next               'ignore any error
Set s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sName) 'see if we can grab the sheet
On Error GoTo 0                    'stop ignoring errors

If s Is Nothing Then    'sheet didn't exist: create it
    Set s = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add( _
      after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    s.Name = sName
    rng.Parent.Rows(1).Copy s.Range("a1") 'copy headers
End If                  'needed a new sheet
'return the first empty cell in column 1
Set CopyTo = s.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Function
```

The problem I'm having is that without a unique identifier I don't know how to get the macro to decipher if a line has changed and update it and I end up with duplicates.  We add to this workbook all year so having the macro update the individual sheets is a big time saver.

To sum up I need a macro that will:

1. Distribute each Master Sheet row to each appropriately labeled worksheet.
2. I need each unique ID# to update that row if anything has changed.
3. I also need to make sure that no duplicates exist on the sheets.

If there is a way to have the macro automatically run on closing the document that would be a bonus but manually running the macro is something I can live with.

---

[Duplicate ROWS and information not updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZRSn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Modify this code

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
```

because it is reading the first column, to this:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("B3"), _
             ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked! I also need to have my Master sheet update any information that changes without adding in the same line (ID#).  I'm trying to research how to do this but so far am not having any luck.  I either end up with 4 lines with the same ID# and different info or I have several lines with the same info and doesn't show any changes :(

Comment: You mean just replace the information for the same ID

Comment: Yes.  Right now every time I run the macro it ads the same lines into the corresponding sheet.  I want to stop that from happening and just update the information. Thanks for answering back Sam :)

Comment: I've added an image of the problem to my original post.  It's at the bottom in a link :)

Comment: You have to find the id for the transaction you want updating then replace the row in the corresponding sheet